# MAX with condition

Tags: mysql

I have this table representing person memberships in groups:

```
+----+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
| id | person_id | group_id | from       | to         |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
| 1  | 1         | 1        | 2014-10-13 | 2014-10-20 |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
| 2  | 1         | 1        | 2014-10-17 | 2014-10-31 |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
| 3  | 1         | 1        | 2014-10-01 | 2014-10-15 |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
| 4  | 1         | 2        | 2014-11-01 | 2014-12-01 |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
```

I want to select the combined membership for each group and person, and a status showing if it's currently active. It's fine if currently "inactive" memberships overlapping with "active" memberships are not combined in the result (though it would be nice if that was possible too). Today is 2014-10-17, so the result set in this case should be:

```
+-----------+----------+------------+------------+----------+
| person_id | group_id | from       | until      | status   |
+-----------+----------+------------+------------+----------+
| 1         | 1        | 2014-10-13 | 2014-10-31 | ACTIVE   |
+-----------+----------+------------+------------+----------+
| 1         | 2        | NULL       | NULL       | INACTIVE |
+-----------+----------+------------+------------+----------+
```

So for group 1 the values used were `from` in row 1, `until` in row 2, and row 3 was excluded even though its `until` overlapped with `from` in row 1. I would prefer if the `from` in row 3 was used instead, but it's fine if the result set looks like above. Group 2 is inactive because it didn't have any row with `from` < NOW() AND `until` > NOW().

Right now I have this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE combinedRows ENGINE = MEMORY
SELECT
    `person_id`,
    `group_id`,
    MIN(`from`) AS `from`,
    MAX(`until`) AS `until`,
    'ACTIVE' AS `status`
FROM
    `memberships`
WHERE
    `person_id` = @updated_person
    AND `group_id` = @updated_bgroup
    AND `from` < NOW()
    AND `until` > NOW()
GROUP BY
    `person_id`,
    `group_id`;
```

Followed by INSERT IGNORE INTO combinedRows SELECT *inversed*... Basically I would like to do the same thing in a single query (for performance reasons). Something equivalent to this "pseudo code":

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE combinedRows ENGINE = MEMORY
SELECT
    `person_id`,
    `group_id`,
    MIN(`from` WHERE `from` < NOW() and `until` > NOW()) DEFAULT NULL AS `from`,
    MAX(`until` WHERE `from` < NOW() and `until` > NOW()) DEFAULT NULL AS `until`,
    IF(*something*, 'ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE') AS `status`
FROM
    `memberships`
WHERE
    `person_id` = @updated_person
    AND `group_id` = @updated_bgroup
GROUP BY
    `person_id`,
    `group_id`;
```

Is this possible?? Or should I just forget it and not worry about the performance? Or should I change the database design somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  `person_id`,
  `group_id`,
  MIN(CASE WHEN `from` < NOW() and `until` > NOW() THEN `from` ELSE NULL END) AS `from`,
  MAX(CASE WHEN `from` < NOW() and `until` > NOW() THEN `until` ELSE NULL END) AS `until`,
  MIN(CASE WHEN `from` < NOW() and `until` > NOW() THEN 'ACTIVE' ELSE 'INACTIVE' END) AS `status`
FROM
  `memberships`
WHERE
  `person_id` = @updated_person
  AND `group_id` = @updated_bgroup
GROUP BY
  `person_id`,
  `group_id`;
```

*Explanation:*

You can put any expression in aggregate functions (`MAX`, `MIN`, ...). `NULL` values are ignored and `MIN` (or `MAX`) is calculated from values witch are not `NULL`.

If you look at:

```
MIN(CASE WHEN `from` < NOW() and `until` > NOW() THEN 'ACTIVE' ELSE 'INACTIVE' END)
```

then the trick here is: if there are rows which satisfies condition, then 'ACTIVE' is returned because 'ACTIVE' is less than 'INACTIVE' when compared as strings.